# Laravel 5.6 Class xmlrpcmsg not found

Tags: php, laravel-5.6, xml-rpc

I'm trying to get xmlrpc to work for an API, The Client, Value and Request classes already work. But the xmlrpcmsg class keeps getting the error:

`Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\xmlrpcmsg()`

I'm using laravel 5.6 and have installed xmlrpc using composer.

composer.json

```
"require": {
    "phpxmlrpc/phpxmlrpc": "4.4.*"
},
```

I have them included in my controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

include __DIR__ . '/../../../vendor/autoload.php';
include __DIR__ . '/../../../vendor/phpxmlrpc/phpxmlrpc/lib/xmlrpc.inc';
include __DIR__ . '/../../../vendor/phpxmlrpc/phpxmlrpc/lib/xmlrpcs.inc';

use App\Http\Controllers\CollectorConfig;
use PhpXmlRpc\Client;
use PhpXmlRpc\Value;
use PhpXmlRpc\Request;

class Collector extends CollectorConfig{
    // Class constants
    const XMLRPC_LOGIN = 'login';

    ~~~ Some more constants and code ~~~

    static function connect($service = 'object'){
        $msg = new xmlrpcmsg(self::XMLRPC_LOGIN);
        $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval(self::$dbname, xmlrpcval::$xmlrpcString));
        $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval(CollectorConfig::API_USER, xmlrpcval::$xmlrpcString));
        $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval(CollectorConfig::API_PASSWORD, xmlrpcval::$xmlrpcString));
        $resp = $client->send($msg);
    }
}
```

Does anybody know how I can get this class to work in my controller?

Comment: You're supposed to include composer's generated autoload.php file. In your case it looks like it'd be `require_once __DIR__ . '/../../../vendor/autoload.php';` You don't need to include anything else.

Comment: Sorry forgot to add this to the example. but it is in there

Comment: You're in a namespace, so you'll want to use `new \xmlrpcmsg(...)` (with a backslash) to target the root namespace.

Comment: The backslash worked. Thank you

Comment: Alternatively, you may add `use \xmlrpcmsg`  on top of your script, then use the non-prefixed name when referring to the class. You should preferably learn about this and not just "blindly" do it, as it's a very important concept to know about.